# Asset manager, get asset id?

Tags: android

I can open my file using an asset manager, it is located under assets, I was just wondering if i could get the files id (so I can use it with sound pool) and if it was possible to copy from assets folder to raw folder at runtime (dont ask me why I want to do this).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to copy from assets to raw folder at runtime. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the file into raw folder why you use the assets folder. if your application run with raw folder then no need to store the file on assets. there is no way to copy the assets file to any other folder.